# Loading an exploded war in WSO2 Application Server 4.1.2

Tags: web-applications, wso2, war, exploded

Is it possible to load an exploded war as a web app on wso2 application server version 4.1.2? If so, how do I load it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can deploy a exploded war. Simply copy your folder to /repository/deployment/server/webapps folder.

WSO2 AS is few releases ahead from 4.1.2. Currently it is 5.2.1. So its better if you update to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm on a project that will not allow me to upgrade from 4.1.2 otherwise I would have upgraded. I have to work with they give me!

Comment: I tried dropping the folder into the webapps folder but the web app is behaving like there is no exploded war.  For example when I try to reach a xyz.wsdl in the web-inf fodler on vanilla tomcat 7 I can dispaly the wsdl.  In wso2 app server I get and error:

INFO (org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator) - Could not find axis2.xml, loading default org/apache/axis2/deployement.axis2_default.xml from classpath